# Will installing latest version of IE also install windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

I have a windows 7 laptop with IE 8 and would like to upgrade to latest verrsion of IE but definitely do not want Windows 10. I have already done all the recommended things to prevent Microsoft from automatically upgrading to Windows 10 (turned off automatic upgrade,etc.) but am concerned that might happen if I download and install newest IE.

Comment: What version of IE are you talking about? IE 11 is the latest version that will install on W7.

Comment: if you're scared about the Win10 upgrade offer in IE, set this value in registry: https://twitter.com/TheWack0lian/status/708367098989441024

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nothing to worry about.  Internet Explorer 11 is compatible with Windows 7.  It will not upgrade the OS.

Comment: How do you know this?

Comment: Because people upgrade I.E.all the time.

Comment: I just upgraded to IE11 on my W7 laptop the other day, it did not upgrade the OS..